# How to detect when an input is not on the entity list

Tags: entity, chatbot, ibm-watson

I am creating a chatbot for my store. The store has 10 categories (A, B, C...), each category has types of products(1 to 10). It is not a problem when the user ask for a product not on the list? I just want to tell them I do not sell this kind of product.

category: A, B, C, D..., I, J

category_A: A1, A2, A3 ...

category_B: B1, B2, B3....

I want to order AA

--> Sorry, we do not have this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder node which triggers when the bot identify the `order` intention and inside the folder you create a node for each category entity and the last node shall trigger with `anything_else` condition indicating you don't have the product on you list.

Bot Structure:
folder node -> triggers in `order` intention
-- Common node -> triggers in `category` entity
-- Common node -> triggers in `category_A` entity
-- Common node -> triggers in `category_B` entity
-- Common node -> triggers in `anything_else` special condition anwering you do not have this product

Example:
[image]